# Stop xcode/objective c/iphone from flattening my folder structure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, directory

I'm loading basic(no server) local webpages(included in the application) which use a number of javascript/css libraries and it seems when I run my iphone application that I'm building, all the folders gets flattened and therefore breaks the webpage.

Is there anyway to stop certain folders from getting flattened in my application? Is there such a option in xcode?

I really don't want to go through all my libraries and manually edit them every time we update them.

Comment: You need to give more detail. What applications are you running? what server software? what is the before and after state of the directories, etc.

Comment: It's an application I'm building. Has nothing to do with the webpages themselves, but they are not running under a server. All folders in a iphone application gets flatten and that's what's happening here.

Comment: Are these folders added within your Xcode project?  Are they files that are downloaded later on by your application?  It's hard to understand what you're describing here.

Comment: They were included in my app. But already found the solution and posted below. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just for future reference, The Bundle Programming Guide, or whatever similar named Resource thingy has this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution in keeping the folder structure: http://majicjungle.com/blog/123/
Also had another problem where Javascript files weren't being bundled into my app, had to manually add them to the project resources.